# How to force right resource file to be used when calling from another module

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

Here is the scenario  (newbie to spark scala so kindly bear with me)

1) I have  module A  and a config file under resources folder. Class C in module A reads this config to get information about the file paths

2) i am trying to call Class C (module A)  from Module B (after importing the dependencies of Module A in module B)

3) Issue i am facing is  Class C (module) code  when invoked from Module B , is using the config  from Module B instead of its own config in Module A

Note : code works perfectly when i call with in Module A but once i move this code to Module B its using the resources file in Module B instead of Module A resource file.
both the configs have same name.

Comment: Add information about how you load the config files and where they are located. I assume this is classpath issue: JVM loads the first file that has this path which it finds in the classpath, so if the file is located in same module with the same path as in another module it would load the file from the same module.

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion in regard to my original answer, which assumed Lightbend Config (commonly used in the Scala world), it's been discovered that some sort of `config.xml` is in `src/main/resources` for the respective modules.  These files both end up on the classpath and each module attempts (by an at this point unspecified means) to load the `config.xml` resource.

The JVM when asked to load resources always loads the first which matches.

The easiest way in a small set of projects to address this collision is to not collide by giving the configs in each project different names.

An alternative which is viable in a larger set of projects is to use [Lightbend Config](https://github.com/lightbend/config) which allows config file inclusion out of the box, as well as the ability to use environment variables to easily override configurations at runtime.

An elaborate strategy for a larger set of projects, depending on how compatible the XML schemas for the various module's `config.xml`s are (if they're being read using a schema) is to define a custom Maven build process which embeds `config.xml`s inside one another so that code in module A and module B can share a `config.xml`: A only cares about the portion of the config which came from A and B only cares about that from B.  I'm not particularly familiar with how one would do this in Maven, but I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Thank you Levi. Not sure what this Lightbend config. means, context is Scala Maven application for Apache Spark in HDInsight using IntelliJ .

Comment: Are you importing `com.typesafe.config` anywhere?  Then your config files are lightbend config.

Comment: No I am not importing this com.typesafe.config. In general,  how can i make sure that if the src\main\resources\config.xml  is existing in more than module in our scala project , how to enforce that code calling this config is using the right file. Sorry if am not clear

Comment: The question as you've written it does not have enough information to actually provide an answer.  You'll need to share the code that loads the `config.xml` for a solution.